# Set list separator length

Tags: html, css, sass

I wanna know how to set the length of list separator. I use this code on my css to make the separator

```
ul li {
border-top: #00000 1px solid;
}
```

I want to set the length of my separator by using padding.
For example I want the separator is started from "t"

[image]

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none; 
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

ul li {
  padding: 0 10px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position :relative;
}

ul li:first-child {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

ul li:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 15px; /* you can change this value */  
  height: 1px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
}

ul li:last-child {
  margin: 0; 
}

ul li:last-child:after {
  content: none;
}

ul li:last-child:after {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, **border-bottom** will give bottom line & **list-style-type** will remove the bullets:

```
ul li {
border-bottom: 1px solid red;
list-style-type: none; 
}
```

Comment: Oh Im sorry, its didnt work. But thank you.